# Is it possible to use AVAudioPlayer and initWithData:error: to play generated sounds?

Tags: ios, core-audio

Is it possible to use `AVAudioPlayer` to play custom sounds (e.g. I will generate sine wave and then play it)? 
The docs say that `AVAudioPlayer` can be used to:

> Play sounds from files or memory buffers

But I can't find example of playing custom generated sounds, only memory buffers that are loaded from file or the internet. Is it possible and where can I find more?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive searches (both searching the documentation and googling) I've concluded that this:

> Play sounds from files or memory buffer

refers to memory buffer that contains formatted audio data. If you have MP3 on your disk or somewhere on the internet, you can load it into memory buffer and then play it. That's what they meant. If you want to play your generated sounds, you can use OpenAL or AudioUnits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with OpenAL:

```
void* bufferData; // your generated sound
int bufferDataLength; // length

alGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
alBufferData(bufferID, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, bufferData, bufferDataLength, 44100);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only interested if AVAudioPlayer can do this ;)